# how to Auto Increment Image slider In Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-services

I am trying to Auto change Images in my Application  which is coming from  Array imgslider[] ,

### I am putting the MY component FILE below

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {HeadService} from '../service/head.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
head_slider: any = [];
imgslider: any = [];

  constructor( public _HeadService: HeadService ) {  }

  slides  = [  ];

slideConfig  = {'slidesToShow': 3, 'slidesToScroll': 4};

  ngOnInit() {

  this._HeadService.getDataa().subscribe(data => {
    this.head_slider = data['articles'];
   console.log(this.head_slider);
        for (let i = 0; i < data['articles'].length; i++) {

            this.slides.push({img: data['articles'][i].urlToImage});
        }
  });
}
```

> In the above Image slider I am using ngx-slick Image slider plugin , Here  slides changes on button click , I want to auto Increment the slider Image.

### I am putting html file below

```
<ngx-slick class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
              <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
    </ngx-slick>

    <button (click)="addSlide()">Add</button>
    <button (click)="removeSlide()">Remove</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoto 2</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.unslick()">unslick</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automatically cycle the images you can for example use a [timer Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) that emits numbers in a specified time interval.

First add a name to the slick component in the template so you can get it also in the code. The template then looks like this:

```
<ngx-slick #slickComponent class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
    <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
          <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
</ngx-slick>
```

Then you can get the component as `ViewChild` in your header component and call the `slickGoTo` method of the component in a subscription to the timer observable. Here is a sample how the header component would look like with this logic added.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { timer, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {HeadService} from '../service/head.service';
import { SlickComponent } from 'ngx-slick';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
head_slider: any = [];
imgslider: any = [];
@ViewChild('slickComponent') slickComponent: SlickComponent;
private timerSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor( public _HeadService: HeadService ) {  }

  slides  = [  ];

slideConfig  = {'slidesToShow': 3, 'slidesToScroll': 4};

  ngOnInit() {

  this._HeadService.getDataa().subscribe(data => {
    this.head_slider = data['articles'];
   console.log(this.head_slider);
        for (let i = 0; i < data['articles'].length; i++) {

            this.slides.push({img: data['articles'][i].urlToImage});
        }
  });

  public ngAfterViewInit() : void {
    this.timerSubscription = timer(1000, 1000).subscribe((nextNumber) => {
      this.slickComponent.slickGoTo(nextNumber % this.slides.length);
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The timer must be started in the `ngAfterViewInit` method because before the component is not available. The first timer parameter specifies after how much time it starts and the second the interval for each next number generated. Because the timer observable generates increasing numbers all the time I use the Modulus (Division Remainder) operator to get only numbers that are valid indexes.

To properly free and stop the timer an `unsubscribe` call in `ngOnDestroy` is needed so it does not continue to run after the component gets destroyed. You can read more about properly disposing Observables in the [documentation of rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#disposing-observable-executions).

Comment: Hello @AlesD  , thanks for the explanation , When I used your code , i am facing problem in using '@ViewChild'   ,   when I write '@ViewChild('slickComponent') slickComponent: SlickComponent;'    ,    A red line appears above SlickComponent which shoes error message , [ts] Cannot find name 'SlickComponent'.

Comment: Hi @AnuragRanjan. I forgot to add the import for the type. You need to add `import { SlickComponent } from 'ngx-slick';` in the imports. Will update the sample.

Comment: I have added another answer that is much more simple. Will leave this one because I might help somebody in a simmilar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is actually to just add it in the config. The slick carousel already supports automatic play of images. See the official [documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). This is the original documentation for the slick library that is wrapped by ngx-slick for use in Angular. So all you need to do is change the slideConfig to include autoPlay like this:

```
slideConfig = {"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4, autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000};
```